Why Postgres query is not using column in Index Condition but uses it in Filter condition
I am running a simple join query, where the table incident_tracker_details is covered by a suitable index. The query is slow because it doesn`t use all the columns in Index Condition, but does use the column as a Filter leading to a large heap searches
Query:
SELECT
    relevant_incidents_per_inventory_item.inventory_id,
    tracker_id
FROM
    relevant_incidents_per_inventory_item
JOIN
    incident_tracker_details
ON
    incident_tracker_details.incident_id = relevant_incidents_per_inventory_item.incident_id
WHERE
    incident_tracker_details.company_id = :companyId
    and incident_tracker_details.division_id = :divisionId
    AND incident_tracker_details.value > 0

the index in use:
create index companyid_divisionId_incidentId_idx
on incident_tracker_details (company_id, division_id, incident_id)
where (value > 0) include (tracker_id); 

the relevant_incidents_per_inventory_item does not have any relevant indexes and the table is very small (few hundreds of rows).
the actual query plan:
QUERY PLAN
    Hash Join  (cost=6901.58..6913.72 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=90.663..315.278 rows=522 loops=1)
      Hash Cond: (incident_tracker_details.incident_id = relevant_incidents_per_inventory_item.incident_id)
      ->  Index Only Scan using companyid_divisionId_incidentId_idx on incident_tracker_details  (cost=0.57..12.68 rows=6 width=16) (actual time=0.039..202.787 rows=246774 loops=1)
            Index Cond: ((company_id = '777704491747470679'::bigint) AND (division_id = '777795770460846005'::bigint))
            Heap Fetches: 124039
      ->  Hash  (cost=6900.88..6900.88 rows=10 width=8) (actual time=86.704..86.709 rows=259 loops=1)
            ...not relevant part
    Planning Time: 0.518 ms
    Execution Time: 315.402 ms

Why is the "incident_id" not part of the Index Cond? this leads to retrieving all the rows under companyId, divisionId , and then the engine has to filter all the rows for those having incident_tracker_details.incident_id = relevant_incidents_per_inventory_item.incident_id
I expected to see all the columns used in the Index Condition, leading to fast retrieval of only the relevant data

Your question doesn't make sense.  You say is used as a Filter condition, but there is no Filter condition shown in the plan.

rows=246774 in 202.787 milliseconds is not that bad. And ...not relevant part could be the relevant part, just like the DDL for both tables and all indexes on these tables.

@jjanes the index columns used are under "Index Cond:" and the data filter is under "Hash Cond:" because of the join. Hope it clarifies the question

"this leads to retrieving all the rows under companyId, divisionId, and then the engine has to filter all the rows for those having [an accompanying] relevant_incidents_per_inventory_item" - well that's exactly what you want, no? (Or at least it's exactly what the query says). Did you expect a nested loop join, where postgres would retrieve all relevant_incidents_per_inventory_items, then find the incident_tracker_details (and whether they exist) for each of them (according to the index)?

@Bergi I want the index to be used to retrieve those entries. Instead what we see is index not used properly leading to those 124K Heap Fetches. So ideally, hash join or a nested loop where for each relevant_incidents_per_inventory_item.incident_id will be matched a incident_tracker_details.incident_id.
From what i seen further it is a behaviour not related to the join itself, rather an index usage pattern when dealing with multiple incident_id lookups. See my simplified example below.

@Constant The index is used, just not for the incident_id: for a hash join you need to retrieve all possible input rows. And the planner judges that retrieving all details per company division (just once), then hash-joining them with the relevant incidents, is more efficient than retrieving the relevant incidents and then for each of them finding the details per company division (your desired index usage).

@Constant However, this judgement may be clouded by misestimate. Notice the planner did expect 6 incident_tracker_details but the query found 246774, and it did expect 10 relevant_incidents_per_inventory_item but the query found 259.

@Bergi this is exactly what I am explaining - the index is used only on 2 levels company_id, division_id, and then all 246k rows under these levels are filtered for  incident_id leading also to 124K Heap Fetches, instead of directly accessing those 6 rows using 6 tree searches.

@Constant It cannot directly access only 6 rows, because it doesn't know which incident_id to search for! It would have to do 259 index searches, from the 259 rows (of 10 estimated) of the relevant_incidents_per_inventory_item fetched first.

@Constant, please update the post with the full explain plan. In general, don't elide sections just because you think that they aren't relevant; especially when seeking explanations about query behavior. As Frank Heikens mentioned, the omitted details might be important. That one is asking for help understanding query execution details, might indicate that one lacks sufficient understanding to know which details are relevant.

I see.  There is something specifically called a "Filter Cond", and it differs from both "Index Cond" and "Hash Cond".  Anyway, the planner can't make good decisions when the stats are crap, which yours clearly are (although I don't know why they lead to this particular bad decision).  Try again after running VACUUM ANALYZE on both tables.

The reason incident_id isn't part of Index Cond: is because it isn't part of the selection criteria associated with incident_tracker_details. The only indexed columns mentioned in the WHERE clause are company_id and division_id. Although incident_id is used in the join criteria, it is not part of the selection criteria and thus has no part in the conditions used for the index only scan. The query engine has to get all incident_id values associated with the selection criteria to identify the rows in relevant_incidents_per_inventory_item that satisfy the join condition.
If relevant_incidents_per_inventory_item has an index with incident_id as its first column, then the join criteria can be checked with an index scan. If there is no such index, then the join condition will be evaluated by using a full table scan and filtering for rows that have incident_id values matching those found by the index only scan of companyid_divisionId_incidentId_idx. Since you elided the portion of the explain plan associated with relevant_incidents_per_inventory_item and didn't include all relevant DDL in the post, there isn't any way for us to determine which of these was the case.

This is incorrect, the planner does not require the search criteria to be in the selected columns for index filtering use. For the experiment, I tried adding the incident_id to the selection criteria and the plan has not changed (as I expected).
Also, the relevant_incidents_per_inventory_item doesn't have any index on relevant columns but we are talking now on the incomplete use of index on incident_tracker_details table . The planner has to find all join keys in both tables anyway, so why it does not use the available fast index for the search on one of tables at least?

@Constant, you've apparently confused selected columns and selection criteria (perhaps I should have used the equivalent term, search criteria to avoid such confusion). Adding a condition to the WHERE clause alters the selection criteria: adding a column to the select list does not. The index is being used; however, instance_id isn't part of the index condition because the instance_id values that will be found in relevant_incidents_per_inventory_item aren't yet known.

I tried to find the answer to the incomplete index usage behaviour, and in order to simplify the case I removed the join condition and built a simple query targeting the companyId, divisionId, incidentId index. What I discovered is that when the query has a single incident_id value, the index is used fully and all columns are in Index Cond.
On the other hand, when I have multiple (more than 1) incident_ids either in OR or in IN form, the index is used partially what leads to the slow Heap Fetches as seen before.
Simplified query:
SELECT
    tracker_id
FROM
    bi.incident_tracker_details
WHERE
    company_id = :companyId
    AND division_id = :divisionId
        (incident_id = 234234234234234234 OR incident_id = 333333333333333333)   
    AND value > 0;

Query plan for 2 incident_id values using OR.  Notice the Heap Fetches, and index on Index Cond only company_id and division_id columns, the incident_id is in Filter.
    QUERY PLAN
    Index Only Scan using companyid_divisionId_incident_id_idx on incident_tracker_details  (cost=0.57..8.72 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=103.485..103.485 rows=0 loops=1)
      Index Cond: ((company_id = '4478704491747470679'::bigint) AND (division_id = '4514095770460846005'::bigint))
      Filter: ((incident_id = '234234234234234234'::bigint) OR (incident_id = '333333333333333333'::bigint))
      Rows Removed by Filter: 249705
      Heap Fetches: 20397
    Planning Time: 0.155 ms
    Execution Time: 103.512 ms

On the other hand, same query with a single incident_id value. The Heap Fetches is 0 and the execution time is almost 0:
    QUERY PLAN
    Index Only Scan using companyid_divisionId_incident_id_idx on incident_tracker_details  (cost=0.57..8.59 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=0 loops=1)
      Index Cond: ((company_id = '4478704491747470679'::bigint) 
                    AND (division_id = '4514095770460846005'::bigint) 
                    AND (incident_id = '234234234234234234'::bigint))
      Heap Fetches: 0
    Planning Time: 0.125 ms
    Execution Time: 0.042 ms

this leads me to believe that the behaviour we seen in the original question and in this simplified case is a result of planner wrongfully deciding to scan the incident_id level instead of traversing the tree for each incident_id value.
I will glad to understand why it does so though...

Descending an index twice is a lot of work, compared to descending an index once and then scanning through (incorrectly believed to be) 6 rows.

Because index companyid_divisionId_incidentId_idx is not unique on (company_id, division_id, incident_id), there might be multiple rows for each set of values. The planner doesn't know how many rows might match. Data statistics determine the specific methods that might be used. In a test environment I set up with 100 companies, 10 divisions per company, 10000 unique incident IDs, and 1000000 rows, the planner elected to perform two bitmap index scans followed by a bitmapOr. More details about the data characteristics are needed to replicate the behavior described in the original post.

@JohnH good mention of the uniqueness of the index. I will see if I can replace the existing index with a unique one (first has to check if it is applicable). Thanks for the idea.

@JohnH checked you idea, the company_id,division_id,incident_id are not unique and can have tens of entries. Probably this is one of the sources for the inefficient plan seen here

@Constant, the plan is not inefficient. It is making effective and efficient use of the indexes.
